# MySQL - Select data with a JOIN but with WHERE clauses applying to complex and distinct perimeters

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.6

I have a MySQL 5.6 database and fail to make a complex query, which (i think) involve multiple joins.

The first table (T1) is `Hobby_ideas_articles` and records looks like this:

```
hobby_idea_article_id= 1,
hobby_id = 6
url= 'http://exo.example.com',
author = 'john@example.com'

hobby_idea_article_id= 2,
hobby_id = 3
url= 'http://exo.example2.com',
author = 'john@example.com'

hobby_idea_article_id= 3,
hobby_id = 6
url= 'http://exo.example3.com',
author = 'eric@example.com'

hobby_idea_article_id= 4,
hobby_id = 7
url= 'http://exo.example4.com',
author = 'john@example.com'

hobby_idea_article_id= 5,
hobby_id = 6
url= 'http://exo.example5.com',
author = 'nestor@example.com'

hobby_idea_article_id= 7,
hobby_id = 6
url= 'http://exo.example6.com',
author = 'ginger@example.com'

hobby_idea_article_id= 8,
hobby_id = 6
url= 'http://exo.example8.com',
author = 'derek@example.com'

hobby_idea_article_id= 9,
hobby_id = 6
url= 'http://exo.example9.com',
author = 'derek@example.com'
```

The second table (T2) called `Past_Customer_sent_messages` lists ALL messages from the past, notably with the information of who sent it (`customer_id` -> pointing to another table called `Customers` which is not needed in this current question) and to whom (`recipient`), and records look like this

```
past_customer_sent_message_id = 5
hobby_id = 7,
customer_id = 4,
recipient = "john@example.com",
sent_at= "2019-09-10 00:00:00"

past_customer_sent_message_id = 6
hobby_id = 999,
customer_id = 4,
recipient = "eric@example.com",
sent_at= "2019-09-18 00:00:00"

past_customer_sent_message_id = 7
hobby_id = 999,
customer_id = 4,
recipient = "nestor@example.com",
sent_at= "2019-07-18 00:00:00"
```

Even if there is currently no foreign key between T1 and T2, one critical information is that
the T1 `'author'` is the `'recipient"` that will appear on T2 if a customer sends a message to him.

I'm not sure if it matters for the present question, but there is a `Customer` table (a `past_customer_sent_messages` belongs to a `customer`, a `customer` has multiple `past_customer_sent_messages`) and a `Hobbies` table (a `Hobby_ideas_article` belongs to a `hobby` but a `hobby` can have multiple `Hobby_ideas_articles`).

In my javascript file, before writing the SQL statement, I **have 2 inputs with already given values I'll need to use at some point in the SQL statement**:

- hobby_id = HOBBY_ID_INPUT_I_HAVE , for example `6`
- customer_id = CUSTOMER_ID_INPUT_I_HAVE, for example `4`

What I want is to **retrieve ALL the records from the `Hobby_ideas_articles` table (T1) where `hobby_id = HOBBY_ID_INPUT_I_HAVE` with 2 conditions/restrictions**:

- **condition1:** the recipient (ex: `'john@example.com`'), no matter WHAT (i.e no matter the `hobby_id-S = plural` it's connected to via `'author'` column on T1, and no matter the `customer_id-S = plural` it's connected to via `'recipient'` on T2), has never been sent an message (`sent_at` column on T2) in the **past 3 hours.** Again, this applies across all past messages to this `'recipient'` (very important it means not only on the T1 'authors' that would match `hobby_id = HOBBY_ID_INPUT_I_HAVE = 6`).
- **condition2:** the author has not been messaged in the **past 30 days** by the customer who has `customer_id = CUSTOMER_ID_INPUT_I_HAVE`. Here it applies to this specific customer (but across any hobby!).

A part I find particularly challenging intellectually as I would be tempted to put as a WHERE `hobby_id = HOBBY_ID_INPUT_I_HAVE` (see below) but it feels wrong because then, how to do I implement the condition1 which applies to ALL the messages, and should not be applied to only those with `hobby_id = HOBBY_ID_INPUT_I_HAVE`...hard! Same kind of difficulty for condition2

Maybe I could/should add a new column called `hobby_idea_id` that I would put on T2 which would be a foreign key between the 2 tables as a `Past_Customer_sent_message` belongs in a way to a Hobby_ideas_article and a Hobby_ideas_article has many Past_Customer_sent_messages ?

Today I have this but I don't even know on what to put the 'ON' clause of the join...and can't set the correct statement.

```
SELECT             
          hia.query_result_id,
          hia.url,
          hia.title,
          hia.article_publication_day,
          hia.media_name,
          hia.author_full_name,
          hia.author_first_name,
          hia.author_last_name,
          hia.author_email,
          ces.sent_at
FROM
          Hobby_ideas_articles hia
LEFT JOIN
          Past_Customer_sent_messages ces
ON
          # WHAT CLAUSE ???
WHERE
          hia.hobby_id = HOBBY_ID_INPUT_I_HAVE AND         
          hia.author IS NOT NULL
          # more conditions but how to assert them ??
```

How to achieve this ?

The desired output would be:

```
hobby_idea_article_id= 5,
hobby_id = 6
url= 'http://exo.example5.com',
author = 'nestor@example.com'
last_email_sent_at = "2019-07-18 00:00:00"

hobby_idea_article_id= 7,
hobby_id = 6
url= 'http://exo.example6.com',
author = 'ginger@example.com'
last_email_sent_at = null

hobby_idea_article_id= 8,
hobby_id = 6
url= 'http://exo.example8.com',
author = 'derek@example.com'
last_email_sent_at = null
```

As you can see with my inputs values given as examples (hobby_id = 6 , 
customer_id = 4),

- 'john@example.com' and any hobby_ideas related to him are not part of the output because john has been messaged by customer_id = 4 in the past 30 days already
- 'Eric' and the hobby_ideas related to him could have been part of the output because Eric was messaged by customer_id=6 8 days ago (and not customer_id=4 which is the value we target), BUT unfortunately it was excluded/filtered out because of condition1 : he was messaged at some point 2 hours ago by another customer, so he's out too.
- nestor and the hobby_idea related to him are inside the output because he's unaffected by both because he indeed is related to hobby_id= 6, but his only mail was sent a few months ago.
- ginger and the hobby_idea related to her are inside the output because condition1 and2 are ok given that ginger never emailed anybody: ther's no message at all where she is the recipient
- Also note that if an author would be in the output but has multiple hobby_ideas related to him, then i only want one, that's why derek only appear once with let's say the FIRST hobby_idea but the second one he's one is removed from the output

**Disclaimer**: I come from a Rails background where I used to have ORM (Active Record) making all the chains/joins/ easier more *automagic* and am a bit lost here with the present SQL statement I must write inside my javascript aws lambda file.

Comment: The `ON` condition should presumably be `ON hia.hobby_id = ces.hobby_id`.

Comment: Are you sure you want `LEFT JOIN`? That will return articles that don't have any messages.

Comment: that's the core issue: I don't think so. I want all hobby ideas WHERE hobby_id is equal toa constant I have (let's say 6, that means this data does NOT come from T2) but...where I need ces.hobby_id would be more inside the WHEREs...

Comment: Could you show the desired result from the sample data?

Comment: What does `hobby_id-S = plural` mean?

Comment: i'm not sure it's a left join, i'm a sql rookie...maybe an inner join would be better. As my where clause does not involve 2 tables...maybe i dont need even a Join...but then how to make my condition1 and 2 without a Join, that's my issue...maybe the join could be on t1.author=t2.recipient?

Comment: @Barmar thanks for the help. I worte plural to make very clear there are multiple hobbies, hence hobby_id-s, related to a given author as an author can appear in multiple hobbiy_ideas

Comment: I'll write now the desired output

Comment: I guess it's `ON hia.author = ces.recipient`?

Comment: Added more examples to show you based on my inputs(coming form my javascript calculations BEFORE my SQL statement, meaning they're available to use when doing the SQL) what would be the output

Comment: Also added notes to explain why each person is inside the output or left outside

Comment: The desired output doesn't have the `sent_at` column, which is the only reason for joining with `ces`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199657/discussion-between-barmar-and-mathieu).

Comment: yes it has sent_at...I do need some data from T2 inside the select.that's why i thought i need a join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `recipient NOT IN (SELECT ...)` and `author NOT IN (SELECT ...)` to exclude the participants that match your conditions 1 and 2.

```
SELECT             
          hia.query_result_id,
          hia.url,
          hia.title,
          hia.article_publication_day,
          hia.media_name,
          hia.author_full_name,
          hia.author_first_name,
          hia.author_last_name,
          hia.author_email,
          ces.sent_at
FROM
          Hobby_ideas_articles hia
LEFT JOIN
          Past_Customer_sent_messages ces
ON
          hia.author = ces.recipient 
            AND ces.recipient NOT IN (
                SELECT recipient
                FROM Past_Customer_sent_messages
                WHERE sent_at > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 HOUR)
            )
WHERE
          hia.hobby_id = HOBBY_ID_INPUT_I_HAVE AND         
          hia.author IS NOT NULL
          AND hia.author NOT IN (
            SELECT recipient
            FROM Past_Customer_sent_messages
            WHERE customer_id = CUSTOMER_ID_INPUT_I_HAVE
            AND sent_at > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
          )
```

The condition on `ces` has to be in the `ON` clause so that you'll get `sent_at = NULL` for articles that don't have any matching rows.

Comment: Added a response with full code here for discussion before editjng the post https://gist.github.com/misner/ef04a465434d544d89d146c95519b00f

Comment: Also created a new question with the basis of your answer to address a question regarding high concurrency and locks (beyond the simple select..for update): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58012844/my-sql-5-6-how-to-prevent-reads-on-rows-selected-by-a-previous-sql-statement-p